# what is the equivalent of clang builtin __c11_atomic_compare_exchange_strong in MSVC?

Tags: c++11, visual-c++

I'm porting a program into Windows environment which directly uses clang's language extension [`__c11_atomic_compare_exchange_strong`](http://hogbergs.org/localdoc/llvm37/clang/html/LanguageExtensions.html) for some CAS operations.

What is the equivalent of that function in MSVC (2015, 2017)?

Comment: Why don´t you use std::atomic which is platform independent, it has compare_exchange_strong. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @0xBADF00, it would desirable to replace these calls with their [C++11 std::atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_compare_exchange) equivalents. MSVC has [full support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) for `std::atomic`, since VS 2012.

However, if for some reason you don't want to do that (for example, you want your code to compile on VS 2010), the Visual C++ equivalents of `std::atomic_compare_exchange_strong` are the [`InterlockedCompareExchange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683560(v=vs.85).aspx) functions. Note these functions do not use templates, and thus there are variants for primitives of differents sizes, such as [`InterlockedCompareExchange64`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683562(v=vs.85).aspx). As such, they can't be used as a direct replacement, as you will need to use the appropriate version for the type being used.